# update-rc.d disable/remove will not remove etc/init.d/rc* references

Tags: linux, daemon, startup

I have created a daemon using the Debian init.d skeleton which successfully runs as a service. I've also used:

```
sudo update-rc.d /etc/init.d/pirservice.sh defaults
```

to get the daemon running at boot and closing nicely when issuing a shutdown command.

However, I have since tried to remove the start at boot service using the following:

```
sudo update-rc.d /etc/init.d/pirservice.sh remove
```

On checking for completion using:

```
ls -l /etc/rc?.d/*pirservice.sh
```

The scripts is still linked in all 6 rc?.d folders and sure enough still loads at boot

when I try to use the following:

```
sudo update-rc.d /etc/init.d/pirservice.sh disable
```

I get the following error:

```
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
update-rc.d: error: cannot find a LSB script for /etc/init.d/pirservice.sh
```

My scripts is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

# /etc/init.d/pirservice.sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          myservice
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Put a short description of the service here
# Description:       Put a long description of the service here
### END INIT INFO

# Change the next 3 lines to suit where you install your script and what you want to     call it
DIR=/usr/local/bin/myservice
DAEMON=$DIR/pir.py
DAEMON_NAME=pir

# This next line determines what user the script runs as.
# Root generally not recommended but necessary if you are using the Raspberry Pi GPIO from Python.
DAEMON_USER=root

# The process ID of the script when it runs is stored here:
PIDFILE=/var/run/$DAEMON_NAME.pid

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

do_start () {
    log_daemon_msg "Starting system $DAEMON_NAME daemon"
    start-stop-daemon --start --background --pidfile $PIDFILE --make-pidfile --user     $DAEMON_USER --startas $DAEMON
    log_end_msg $?
}
do_stop () {
    log_daemon_msg "Stopping system $DAEMON_NAME daemon"
    start-stop-daemon --stop --pidfile $PIDFILE --retry 10
    log_end_msg $?
}

case "$1" in

    start|stop)
        do_${1}
        ;;

    log_end_msg $?
}
 do_stop () {
    log_daemon_msg "Stopping system $DAEMON_NAME daemon"
    start-stop-daemon --stop --pidfile $PIDFILE --retry 10
    log_end_msg $?
}

 case "$1" in

    start|stop)
        do_${1}
        ;;

    restart|reload|force-reload)
        do_stop
        do_start
        ;;

    status)
        status_of_proc "$DAEMON_NAME" "$DAEMON" && exit 0 || exit $?
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/$DEAMON_NAME {start|stop|restart|status}"
        exit 1
        ;;

esac
exit 0
```

Can anyone offer any guidance?

Answer (score 4):

OK. I couldn't see any obvious error with the init script. so I forced the removal as follows:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f /etc/init.d/pirservice.sh remove
```

If anyone can figure out why I have the LSB error I would be appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

The man page says

> **update-rc.d** [-n] [-f] *name* remove
>
> **update-rc.d** updates  the System V style init script links /etc/rcrunlevel.d/NN*name* whose target is the script /etc/init.d/*name*.

So you should use

> **update-rc.d** *pirservice.sh* disable

instead. 
For good style you should update information within the `INIT INFO` block.
Additionaly you could remove the `.sh` extension for a nicer name.